# Cleanest way to wrap a sequence of elements in another element

Tags: javascript, html

I have these bits of HTML:

```
<div class="main_class">
    <div class="first_part"><img src="0.gif" /></div>
    <span>...</span>
    <img src="1.gif" />
    <img src="2.gif" />
    <img src="3.gif" />
    <div class="end_part"></div>
</div>
```

The amount of images between the span and div is variable, and I'm trying to wrap them with an anchor tag to get a result like this:

```
<div class="main_class">
    <div class="first_part"><img src="0.gif" /></div>
    <span>...</span>
    <a href="link">
        <img src="1.gif" />
        <img src="2.gif" />
        <img src="3.gif" />
    </a>
    <div class="end_part"></div>
</div>
```

I thought it would be as simple as getting hold of the span and using outerHTML to add an open ended  tag:

```
mc = document.querySelectorAll(".main_class:not(.modified)");
for (i = 0; i < mc.length; i++) {
    mc[i].classList.add('modified');
    mc[i].children[1].outerHTML += '<a href="link">';
    mc[i].lastElementChild.outerHTML = '</a>' + mc[i].lastElementChild.outerHTML
}
```

But then I realized that the browser is too smart and auto closes the tag. Is there a relatively simple way to do this that I'm unaware of?

Comment: Wow you guys are fast. I continued trying to figure it out on my own and finally figured it out and now I see two other solutions (mine was like trincot's, but I'm not familiar with `let`)

Comment: Glad you figured it out! :-) About `let`: [More here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), but the place trincot used it, [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) probably would have been more appropriate (since the value of `mc` is never changed within the loop body).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `outerHTML` for this, but use methods like `document.createElement`, `.appendChild`, `.insertBefore`, ...:

```js
for (let mc of document.querySelectorAll(".main_class:not(.modified)")) {
    mc.classList.add('modified');
    let anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.href = "link";
    for (let child of [...mc.children]) {
        if (child.tagName === 'IMG') {
            mc.insertBefore(anchor, child);
            anchor.appendChild(child);
        }
    }
    console.log(mc.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div class="main_class">
    <div class="first_part"><img src="0.gif" /></div>
    <span>...</span>
    <img src="1.gif" />
    <img src="2.gif" />
    <img src="3.gif" />
    <div class="end_part"></div>
</div>
```

Note: if you wonder why there is `[...mc.children]` instead of just `mc.children`: this is needed to take a copy of the child elements, otherwise the manipulations happening in the loop's body would affect the *live* collection of `mc.children` and make the loop miss some of the elements. T.J.'s `Array.from` will circumvent the same from happening.

Comment: Why constantly move the anchor around?

Comment: (And I **really** need to get used to reaching for `for-of`... :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, only one move of the anchor is really needed, but I was lazy and did not want to rely on the presence of `.end_part` or images. If there are no images, then nothing changes. The insertion point of the anchor is solely determined by the position of the last image found.

Comment: Fair enough. :-)

Comment: Yeah outerHTML was a bad way to go, as I mentioned in the other comment, I'm more familiar with the HTML markup so that's where I start, and I don't know as much about these methods. After a bit more experimentation I did manage to come up with something very similar, though I didn't understand the `let` keyword so I'm not sure how that's working.

Comment: `let` and `const` are ES6 alternatives for `var`: they have block scope and do not hoist.

Comment: Well, they *half*-hoist. :-)

Comment: Indeed, the parser will know of their existence, and will thus mask other variables with the same name from the outer scope, but will raise an error if they are referenced before the declaration. Is that what you meant, @T.J.Crowder?

Comment: @trincot: Yes, exactly that. The so-called "temporal dead zone."

Comment: Ah yes, the temporal dead zone.

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking in markup, but the DOM ([specs](https://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)) isn't markup, it's an object tree. Think in terms of objects. Create an `a` element, then *move* the existing `img` elements into it via `appendChild`, then insert it prior to the `div.end_part` element. (Amongst other things, this means that any event handlers attached to them remain undisturbed, which a round-trip through markup would remove.)

And since you're only going to run this on Chrome, you can happily take advantage of `forEach` on `NodeList` and arrow functions:

```
// Find all unhandled .main_class elements
document.querySelectorAll(".main_class:not(.modified)").forEach(mc => {
    // Mark we've done this one
    mc.classList.add("modified");
    // Create our link
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute("href", "link"); // You can use `a.href = "link"` if it's okay for the attribute to get a resolved value
    // Move the images into it
    Array.from(mc.children).filter(child => child.tagName === "IMG").forEach(img => {
        a.appendChild(img);
    });
    // Insert it before the div.end_part
    mc.insertBefore(a, mc.querySelector("div.end_part"));
});
```

Live Example (I've added a blue border around the link and a red border around the images so we can see where they are):

```js
// Find all unhandled .main_class elements
document.querySelectorAll(".main_class:not(.modified)").forEach(mc => {
    // Mark we've done this one
    mc.classList.add("modified");
    // Create our link
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute("href", "link");
    // Move the images into it
    Array.from(mc.children).filter(child => child.tagName === "IMG").forEach(img => {
        a.appendChild(img);
    });
    // Insert it before the div.end_part
    mc.insertBefore(a, mc.querySelector("div.end_part"));
});
```

```css
a[href=link] {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
img {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_class">
    <div class="first_part"><img src="0.gif" /></div>
    <span>...</span>
    <img src="1.gif" />
    <img src="2.gif" />
    <img src="3.gif" />
    <div class="end_part"></div>
</div>
<div class="main_class">
    <div class="first_part"><img src="0.gif" /></div>
    <span>...</span>
    <img src="1.gif" />
    <img src="2.gif" />
    <img src="3.gif" />
    <div class="end_part"></div>
</div>
<div class="main_class">
    <div class="first_part"><img src="0.gif" /></div>
    <span>...</span>
    <img src="1.gif" />
    <img src="2.gif" />
    <img src="3.gif" />
    <div class="end_part"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are correct, I was thinking in markup terms. It's just what I'm familiar with. I haven't delved heavily into Javascript in a long time so I'm not really familiar with all the "new" DOM stuff. Also, I am totally lost in your script, I will have to analyze it at length when I get a few minutes. Thank you for the reply!

Comment: @therks: No worries! A couple of relevant links for the above: [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (what `querySelectorAll` returns isn't an array, but on *modern* browsers, it also has `forEach`), [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).